# I have code for web scraping an amazon url using Jsoup but, my code doesn't always work

Tags: jsoup

```
public class Amazon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What deal are you looking for on amazon.com? ");
        String mySearch = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" + console.nextLine() + "&ref=nb_sb_noss";
        mySearch = mySearch.replace(' ', '+');
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(mySearch).get();
            Elements cells = doc.getElementsByClass("a-offscreen");
            for(Element cell : cells) {
                System.out.println(cell.text());
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Try a different key word");
        }

    }

}
```

I'm not sure if I just have a logic error, or if it is a problem of a wrong URL. This code works about 20% of the times I run it and successfully prints the cost of a product, and the others it fails and prints nothing. I think the `for(Element cell : cells)` loop is broken somehow. If you could help, it would be much appreciated, thanks!